# Add extra characters to specific rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

How can i add some characters before and after all *.jpg addresses in this table:

```
id  value     type 
1   a.jpg     photo     
2   b         text
3   c.jpg     photo
```

here is what i want as result:

```
id  value                                  type 
1   [img]http://www.b.com/a.jpg[/img]     photo     
2   b                                      text
3   [img]http://www.b.com/c.jpg[/img]     photo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE SAMPLETABLE SET COLUMNNAME=CONCAT('[img]http://www.b.com/',COLUMNNAME,'[/img]') WHERE COLUMNNAME LIKE '%.jpg%'
```

Try above code.Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to do:

```
update t
    set value = replace('[img]http://www.b.com/{0}[/img]', '{0}', value)
    where value like '%.jpg';
```

I like to use `replace()` for constructing strings, because it is easier to see and modify the format of the string.